# How to toggle bool while in a while loop using a key press

Tags: c++, while-loop, keyboard, toggle, console-application

Ive been trying to toggle bool while in a while loop. Im struggling at finding a way to only toggle it once (as when I check if a key has been pressed in the loop it registers it many times). Im somewhat new so I apologize if this is a bad question. Thanks!

```
//Loop

while (true)
{
    //*active* is the bool that I want to toggle
    if (active)
    {

        if (*CRITERIA*)
        {
            *CODE*
        }
    }
    Sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The negation of the current state is the new state you want:

```
active = !active;
```

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but Im wondering how I can make it so that when I release a certain key it will change the bool.

Comment: Put the line to where you check for key release events? `if (key_released) toggle_bool;`?

Comment: Yeah, but I dont know how to check for key release events :/

Comment: Then you should ask about a specific problem you encountered while trying to implement that. And add what library you're using.